# How to run function once without using decorators?

Tags: python

When y < x function should run only once and play only one sound, but when I run script it playes more than one. How to run it only once?

I tried to solve it with decorators, but I failed.

```
def random_choice(x, y):
    random_Process = [Process(target=play_sound0).start(),
    Process(target=play_sound1).start(),
    Process(target=play_sound2).start()]
    if y < x:
        random.choice(random_Process)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    random_choice(50, random.randint(40, 60))
```

Expect: one and random

```
Process(target=play_sound1).start()
```

When run: three and random

```
Process(target=play_sound2).start()
Process(target=play_sound0).start()
Process(target=play_sound1).start()
```

Comment: You have **already** started the processes.

Comment: You should call `start()` only on the chosen process. Or even better only create a process for a chosen sound.

Comment: Why do you want processes at all, if you just want to run one? Why not just call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
random_Process = [Process(target=play_sound0).start(),
    Process(target=play_sound1).start(),
    Process(target=play_sound2).start()]
```

starts *all three* `Process` instances. If you want to start only one, choose `target`:

```
targets = [
  play_sound0,
  play_sound1,
  play_sound2
]

target = random.choice(targets)
Process(target=target).start()
```